# Understanding class type '__main__.ClassName'

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

Code:

```
class Fraction(object):
    def __init__(self, num, denom):
        self.numerator = num
        self.denominator = denom

def main():
    f = Fraction(1, 3)
    print type(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.Fraction'>
```

Question:

1. Why is the type `__main__.Fraction` instead of just `Fraction`?
2. Why is there "." between `__main__` and `Fraction`? "." implies that `Fraction` is a sub-class of `__main__`. But why? Even if I remove `If __name__ == "__main__"` from the code, I still get the same output:

   ```
   class Fraction(object):
   def __init__(self, num, denom):
       self.numerator = num
       self.denominator = denom

   f = Fraction(1,3)
   print type(f)

   output: <class '__main__.Fraction'>
   ```

Comment: Thought experiment: `from datetime import timedelta`, what `type` is `timedelta`? → `datetime.timedelta`. Each object belongs to a module.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `.` means subclass? `.` means attribute.

Comment: @user2357112 that means that attributes can be classes as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. As you have not defined a `__repr__` (or `__str__`) on the class, it's inherited the one from the superclass -- `object` and that how its written there. So, all your class instances are expressed that way. As for the class itself, you need to change the `__repr__`/`__str__` on the metaclass i.e. the class of which our class in question is an instance of; the default metaclass is `type`. `__main__` is the name of the module, here as you are directly executing it, its being considered as a *script* and all scripts have the name `__main__` in Python
2. There's a `.` in between because `Fraction` is an attribute of the script `__main__`, the module; and belongs to the module level scope

---

**Example:**

```
In [47]: class MyMeta(type):
    ...:     def __repr__(cls):
    ...:         return 'Whatever...'
    ...:     

In [48]: class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return 'Howdy...'
    ...:     

In [49]: obj = MyClass()

In [50]: print(obj)
Howdy...

In [51]: print(type(obj))
Whatever...
```

For Python2, you need to define `__metaclass__` as a class attribute.

Comment: Even after defining `__repr__` and `__str__` nothing changes. I defined `__str__` as `return "%d/%d" % (self.numerator, self.denominator)`

Comment: @TheWanderer How are you defining it exactly?

Comment: @TheWanderer Added example to my answer.

Comment: What is `object` then? I thought `object` was the baseclass that we inherit from. But it seems `type` is the baseclass

Comment: @TheWanderer `type` is the metaclass, and `object` is the baseclass;  they are different. metaclass creates and instantiates a class, and base class comes in the time of inheriting attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165346/discussion-between-the-wanderer-and-heemayl).

Answer (score 7):

The name of the script being run is always `__main__`. This is why you check for this specific name, and why classes defined in the script are attributes of it.