# Problems with importing and equality Python

Tags: python, python-import

Lets say we have two python files:

A:

```python
class c(object):pass

def f(obj):
        if type(obj) == c:
                print("Object is of type c!")
        else:
                print("Object is not of type c.")
                print(f"Type c: {c}")
                print(f"Type of the object: {type(obj)}")

o = c()
```

B:

```python
import A

o = A.c()
```

Now lets run A in shell or using the -i arguments in a command line, import B and call f using the object we created in B as an argument.

```python
>>> import B
>>> f(B.o)
Object is not of type c.
Type c: <class '__main__.c'>
Type of the object: <class 'A.c'>
```

Can I some how fix this?

Just to clarify: I do want to execute a program like A and then import a program like B. I just want to know if I can somehow make f work in this context.

Comment: Does `isinstance(B.o, A.c)` give different results?

Comment: Since the problem seems to be the inclusion of the `__main__` in the class type, after a quick google for *"python type \__main\__"* [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54018653/9063935) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846044/9063935) came back

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've cracked it.

When you run

```
python -i A.py
```

this is the same as copying each line from `A.py` into an interactive python shell. This shell is it's own environment, *you are not editing or 'extending' A.py*. Incidentally the name of this environment is `__main__`.

In other words, `python -i A.py` creates a new class `c` different from `A.c` even though the two classes are identical in functionality. When you then `import B`, this imports from `A.py`, ie the 'old' class `A.c`.